# Insertar div en alerta Sweet

Tags: html, jquery, sweetalert

tengo el siguiente div

```
<div class="seguir_compra">
        <div id="siga-comprando" style="">
            <div class="exitoso">
                <h3>Agregaste un producto</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="product-image col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                </div>
                <div class="product-info col-xs-6 col-md-6">                                   
                </div>
            </div>           
        </div>
    </div>
```

lo quiero es que cuando se de click a un boton este div salga dentro de la ventana del sweet alert

```
jQuery('.buy-button').on('click', function() {
    swal({
       html: ''
    });                    
});
```

como podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente selecciona el `div` que deseas incluir en la alerta con `jQuery`, selecciona su `html` y inclúyelo en la llamada de `SweetAlert`.

```js
$('.buy-button').on('click', function() {
    Swal.fire({
       html: $('.seguir_compra').html()
    });                    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<div class="seguir_compra">
        <div id="siga-comprando" style="">
            <div class="exitoso">
                <h3>Agregaste un producto</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="product-image col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                </div>
                <div class="product-info col-xs-6 col-md-6">                                   
                </div>
            </div>           
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <button class='buy-button'>Buy Button</button>
```

Comment: el boton por defecto se podria cambiar por uno custom en html?

Comment: Si, el botón por defecto puede cambiarse y puedes agregar cuantos botones desees usando el html, solo que tendrás tu manualmente que personalizar su comportamiento, es decir, si cierran o abren la alerta, si la cancelan, etc.. Checa esto como ejemplo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39268318/more-than-2-buttons-on-sweetalert-2